# Using Choose and Apply Templates with Mode, vs Complexless Template Matches

Tags: xml, template, xslt

So I have a little XML (Sub)language,
it has 3 elements of interest: `para`, `point`, and `code`

If a `code` occurs inside a `para`, `point` element I want to handle it for inline use,
if not, i want to set it up as it's own display section

Currently I'm doing it like so:

```
  <xsl:template match="code">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="exists(ancestor::para) or exists(ancestor::point)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="inline"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="display"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="code" mode="inline">
    <code><xsl:value-of select="."/></code> 
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="code" mode="display">
    <pre><code><xsl:value-of select="."/></code></pre>
  </xsl:template>
```

Instead of doing it like that i could have just two templates,
one for display and one for inline, and set up the match expressions to work out which it was.

Which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a simple case, I would use a single style-sheet and template without modes. You can leverage the power of predicates to produce a simpler solution like so...

```
<xsl:template match="code">
  <pre><code><xsl:value-of select="."/></code></pre>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="code[ancestor::para | ancestor::point]">
  <code><xsl:value-of select="."/></code> 
</xsl:template>
```

If you are using XSLT 2.0, as opposed to 1.0, an alternate form for the second template would be ...

```
<xsl:template match="code[ancestor::(para|ancestor)]">
  <code><xsl:value-of select="."/></code> 
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not matter a lot for this case, but usually when dealing with XSLT our rule of thumb has been, always to handle different cases with different stylesheets rather than one huge complex XSLT.